# Java Math type casting

Tags: java, math, casting

So I have the following program:

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = (int)Math.pow(11,11);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

I want to print the integer value of 11 to the power of 11. I know that Math.pow(11,11) would return a double 2.85311670611E11 which is correct. But when I type cast it to int I would get 2147483647 which is clearly not correct.

So why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: that's the max value the `int` type can store. what did you expect? also, what do you mean _And how can I fix it_?

Comment: The max value of Int is displayed as the value of the calculation exceeds. Just use a different primitive type. `long`

Comment: @Ousmane Many Diaw I am expecting 285311670611 which is 11 to the power of 11. So does this mean I cannot use int then?

Comment: @Amir use the `long` type which will give you the result of `285311670611`. in the future to get notified on overflow or underflow when using `int` type, do it this way --> `int value = Math.toIntExact((long)Math.pow(11,11));`

Comment: It's vital for programmers to understand how computers handle numeric types and operands, both integral and floating point. In this case study two's-complement 32- and 64-bit integer representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Long for this case.

int, as a signed integer, can be only a number with max 2^32 if it is unsigned, or 32 digits number, in other words its limit is from 0 to 2,147,483,647, and it is giving you just the limit.

Try using Long object, that is 2^64 and will give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's the upper bound of `int` type, you can use `long`  instead or just try `BigInteger` in `java.math.BigInteger`, which never overflows.